# Facebook Open Graph - Issuing HTTP DELETE request

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, jquery, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to remove permissions via an Ajax HTTP DELETE request, but the response I'm getting back is not what the graph api docs say i should be getting.  It says I should be getting a boolean response ("True if the delete succeeded and error otherwise.").  But instead I'm getting an entire object of the permissions list:

```
var revokePermission = function(permName) {

    var revoke_perm_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions" +
                          "?access_token=" + access_token + "&callback=?";

    $.ajax({
        type: "DELETE",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        url: revoke_perm_url,
        data: {'permission': permName},
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
}

revokePermission(permission_name);
```

Here is what I get back:

```
data: Array[1]
    0: Object
        bookmarked: 1
        create_note: 1
        email: 1
        installed: 1
        photo_upload: 1
        publish_actions: 1
        publish_stream: 1
        read_stream: 1
        share_item: 1
        status_update: 1
        user_interests: 1
        user_likes: 1
        user_status: 1
        video_upload: 1
```

Note that the api docs say:

> You can de-authorize an application entirely, or just revoke a
>   specific permission on behalf of a user by issuing an HTTP DELETE to
>   PROFILE_ID/permissions or PROFILE_ID/permissions/PERMISSION_NAME
>   respectively. This request must be made with a value user access_token
>   for the current app.

I understand all this, so when I either issue a request to the specific permission url (ie "/permissions/user_likes/") or to the base permissions url with the permission sent via the ajax data param, they both just return an object of all my current permissions, and the permission I requested to be deleted remains untouched.

However when I set the permission in both the url and the data being sent, it returns an object with an error:

```
Object
    error: Object
    code: 2500
    message: "Cannot specify permission in both the path and query parameter."
    type: "OAuthException"
```

Anyone know what is going on?  Note that the LEGACY REST method of auth.revokeExtendedPermission does indeed work per (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/auth.revokeExtendedPermission/).  It returns a boolean response and the respective permission is deleted.

Solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Full code, tested, returns 'true':

```
var revokePermission = function(permName) {
    var revoke_perm_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        url: revoke_perm_url,
        data: {
           'access_token' : 'access_token_here',
           'permission': permName,
           'method' : 'delete'
        },
        success: function(response){
            alert(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
        }
    });
}
revokePermission("email");
```

Comment: Thanks Andreyul.  Not sure why the Ajax 'type' parameter was not sending.  FYI, I also got to work just by appending "&method=delete" on to the graph url.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Does "type: DELETE" actually work to send a HTTP DELETE request?
The response you're getting back there is the response to a GET request to `/<USER>/permissions`

You can fake a delete request by adding another parameter, 'method' and set that to `delete` when making the GET request, i.e.

```
data: {
'permission': permName
'method' : 'delete'
},
```